# Why is the Dirac operator so important - in both physics and mathematics?

Tags: mathematical-physics, operators

Why is the Dirac operator considered so important - in both physics and (pure) mathematics?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It should be obvious why the Dirac operator is important in physics because of fermions. In mathematics, one could mention the following incomplete list.

1. [Atiyah-Singer Index Theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atiyah%E2%80%93Singer_index_theorem) for the (twisted) spin complex, see e.g., Nakahara, *Geometry, Topology and Physics,* 1990; or Berline, Getzler and Vergne, *Heat Kernels and Dirac Operators,* 2004.
2. [Connes's noncommutative differential geometry](http://www.alainconnes.org/en/downloads.php).
3. [Schrödinger–Lichnerowicz formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lichnerowicz_formula).
4. [Kostant's cubic Dirac operator](http://arxiv.org/abs/math/0208048).

For further information, see also [nLab](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/Dirac+operator).

Answer (score 3):

Because it describes spinors (i.e. behavior of fermions).  String Theory speaks about both bosons and fermions... when passing to a QFT, fermionic wavefunctions become spinor fields, and their dynamics require the Dirac operator.  And this is where all the mathematical importance stems from: QFT and String Theory (topological field theories) is a pure math theory.  In particular, I disagree completely with Noldorin's seemingly naive comment... Clifford algebras and spinors on manifolds is a huge field.

Sorry if this too brief of an explanation (for immediate purposes).

Comment: Hi. Please feel free to elaborate whenever you're interested. :) I can then upvote your answer.